# Visual Studio Code image preview of markdown file

Tags: github, markdown, visual-studio-code

While using [prose.io](http://prose.io) to edit my markdown files, an image can be referenced using the following syntax:

```
![text]({{site.baseurl}}/images/myimage.png)
```

This works fine on Prose preview and also after document is published.

Now I want to start using Visual Studio Code, but it does not properly preview images using this syntax.

How can I make it work?

Comment: `{{site.baseurl}}` is not standard Markdown syntax. Presumably that is some sort of template add-on which is not supported my most Markdown implementations. You will likely need to use a normal path which points at your image file relative to your Markdown document. However, we don't have enough info to tell you what that would be.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Waylan insight, I tried using this syntax, that seems to be the starndard Markdown:

```
![text](../images/myimage.png)
```

*images* folder is in the same level as *posts* folder, where markdown files are located.

This made Visual Studio Code properly preview images. I was also able to properly preview images on prose.io (it seems it also accepts standard Markdown).